# ORACLE -1401 error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure in Oracle 9i which inserts records in a table. The table has a primary key built to ensure duplicte rows doesnot exists.

I am trying to insert a record by calling this stored procedure and it works first time properly. I am again trying to insert a duplicate record and expecting unique constraint violation error. But I am getting 
ORA-01401 inserted value too large for column

I knew its meaning but my query is , if the value inserted is really large then how it got successful in the first attempt.

Table is

```
CREATE TABLE KEY
(
  ID  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  KEY         NUMBER(4)                      NOT NULL,
  INSERT_DATE    DATE,
  WORK_KEY    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SACHINIDX ON KEY
(ID, KEY)
```

Call is
    EXEC SQL EXECUTE
        BEGIN
            keyadd(:id, :key, :wkey);
        END;
    END-EXEC;

Stored Procedure is

```
PROCEDURE keyadd(id IN VARCHAR2, key IN NUMBER, wkey IN VARCHAR2)
{
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO KEY
            (   ID,
                KEY,
                INSERT_DATE,
                WORK_KEY)
            VALUES
            (
                id,
                key,
                SYSDATE,
                wkey
            );
        EXCEPTION
            ROLLBACK;
        COMMIT;
            RETURN;
        END;
}
```

First insert  sqlca.sqlcode is [0]
Second insert sqlca.sqlcode is [-1401]

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table that could be messing with the values?

Comment: Can you show us a small test case that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: Please also show the stored procedure and the call.

Comment: What are the values for `wkey` in the first and the second call?

Comment: Seeing the values should really help with this. You could use `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line()` to log the values to the console.

Comment: For the first call its 59FC9AD0FA5A8932836824B0489B73252C120301A2205154C096B4EB213FA983D5E500B62A469439  and for second its 905BD61AAEC986ACF887DBA7C04D650B61A8818ABEBE1720D810B4A426EB9220558B530D5119315F

Comment: You seem to be missing a WHEN clause in your exception handler.  I don't believe the above code would even compile as shown.

Comment: Yes I missed it when copying here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE KEY
(
  ID  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  KEY         NUMBER(4)                      NOT NULL,
  INSERT_DATE    DATE,
  WORK_KEY    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SACHINIDX ON KEY
(ID, KEY);


create or replace PROCEDURE keyadd(id IN VARCHAR2, key IN NUMBER, wkey IN VARCHAR2)
is
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO KEY
            (   ID,
                KEY,
                INSERT_DATE,
                WORK_KEY)
            VALUES
            (
                id,
                key,
                SYSDATE,
                wkey
            );

        COMMIT;

--      EXCEPTION when others then
--          ROLLBACK;
end keyadd;
/

begin
  keyadd('one', 1, '59FC9AD0FA5A8932836824B0489B73252C120301A2205154C096B4EB213FA983D5E500B62A469439');
  keyadd('one', 1, '905BD61AAEC986ACF887DBA7C04D650B61A8818ABEBE1720D810B4A426EB9220558B530D5119315F');
end;
/
```

gives me the expected `ORA-00001: Unique Constraint...` error, not an ORA-01401. So, without further information its impossible to help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the language the procedure was written in, but this part:

```
     EXCEPTION
         ROLLBACK;
     COMMIT;
         RETURN;
```

raises my eyebrows. Two questions:

- What is this supposed to do?
- Is your issue solved when you remove those lines?

Comment: Whats wrong in these two lines ? And why they needs to be removed

Comment: First of all, you need a WHEN clause after the EXCEPTION keyword.  Secondly, there is no purpose in committing immediately after a rollback.  I doubt this is directly related to your error, but clearly the code you've shown is not the actual code.

Comment: @Sachin: Still waiting for an answer. And maybe this is some extremely poorly copied PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is on your second try, you are providing a value for one of the other columns that is too large.  Looks like this error will supersede the primary key violation.

Comment: All the values are same expect the last column.For the first call its 59FC9AD0FA5A8932836824B0489B73252C120301A2205154C096B4EB213FA983D5E500B62A469439 and for second its 905BD61AAEC986ACF887DBA7C04D650B61A8818ABEBE1720D810B4A426EB9220558B530D5119315F . I cant see any difference in length. :(